# iOS: Timezone issue occurring

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, timezone, nstimezone

Seems that apple timezone is having problems for me right now. I tested the following code below and it isn't working correctly. This is what I have so far.

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

 NSDateFormatter *estDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [estDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
 [estDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

  NSString *stringDate = [estDf stringFromDate:today];
  NSDate *todaydateadjusted = [estDf dateFromString:stringDate];

  NSLog(@"Todays date is %@",[estDf stringFromDate:todaydateadjusted]);
```

This is my NSLog response.
`Todays date is 2015-03-09 16:25:02`

I expected 17:25:02 time not 16:25:02. Since it is 5 o' clock p.m in est time right now it should print out 17 instead of 16. Anyone else having this problem? Perhaps something is wrong with my code.

Comment: Edit: I tried EDT and same result

Comment: If you by any chance have had a delorean ride with a stranger, I envy you. As the answers say, your time is off: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is daylight saving time right now. Shouldn't you use EDT instead?

The other thing is time zone name vs. time zone abbreviation. Take a look at this example - I wrote it in Swift, but I think it should be easy to understand and translate to ObjC.

```
var now = NSDate()
var df = NSDateFormatter()
df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT")
//df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EDT") <- wrong
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let edt = df.stringFromDate(now)
```

If you want to use the full time zone name, use for example
`df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/New_York")`

Comment: It prints correctly 18:30.  Make sure that you either use EDT with abbreviation or America/New_York or similar for timeZoneWithName. At this point your code is for timeZoneWithName, but you pass abbreviation. This gives bogus time for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this:

```
[estDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
```

to this:

```
[esfDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EDT"]];
```